# Wrong verifying Code from sms - react native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have Text Input

```
<TextInput
            value={''}
            ref={ref => {
              this.refPassword = ref;
            }}
            onChangeText={value => this.handleChange(value)}
            textContentType="oneTimeCode"
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
            keyboardType={'number-pad'}
            style={[
              styles.textInput,
              {
                left: selectedIndex * wp('15%'),
                opacity: hideInput ? 0 : 1,
              },
            ]}
          />

handleChange(value) {
this.setState(
  state => {
    return {
      value: (state.value + value).slice(0, CODE_LENGTH.length),
    };
  },
  () => {
    if (this.state.value.length >= CODE_LENGTH.length) {
      this.completePassword();
    }
  },
);
```

}

But, i receive code from sms is incorrect.

Code from SMS: 113498

Code Autofill: 111113

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not the slightest idea. Your code could be doing anything, no idea where the autofill is coming from, how you know what the right code is, where you're checking the correct code. This question is in dire need of any details.

Comment: I have sms api service, I get sms from there to confirm the phone. A regular SMS arrives in which the code, if the focus on the text input can be entered manually or inserted automatically, if the code is automatically entered incorrect

Comment: The content of your change or key press handlers must be incorrect then. If you share those in the question we could perhaps find an answer.

Comment: Changed the post